# Isolating rich text to protect the rest of the HTML on a page?

Tags: html, xhtml, tinymce, rtf, rich-text-editor

I have a TinyMCE Rich Text editor on a form for comments (work tool).   I've had continual problems where coding and characters in the rich text has corrupted the rest of the HTML on a page where those comments are being displayed.

Is there a way to isolate or confine some rich text HTML code in some type of container to protect the rest of the HTML on a page?

I've been trying searches but I can't think of unique keywords that don't overload google results - haven't been able to find anything.    I haven't tried iframes yet but it doesn't seem like a good idea.  I have a modal window displaying a list of comments (which there can often be more than 50 comments), and having 50 iframes in that window (if it worked at all) just doesn't sound right to me?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The only 100% sure way to isolate CSS: use an `Iframe`.

You only need one for the editor itself. Swap it in where the exiting occurs in real-time. Only have one active editor at a time.